# How to find the max value of every column in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I just got stucked in finding the exact query for this requirement.
I want to find the max value in every column.

Here is an example

```
A B C D
-------
0 3 4 1
4 1 5 3
5 9 6 7
7 2 1 6
```

The result should be like this:

```
A | B | C | D |
--------------
7 | 9 | 6 | 7 |
```

That would be more helpful if you could help me out?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX(A) max_a,
       MAX(B) max_b,
       MAX(C) max_c,
       MAX(D) max_d
  FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(a) as A ,max(b) as B  , max(c) as C  , max(d) as D  from 
 tablename
```

Comment: Please, change remove '' from 'A' ,.., because old syntex is mssql,

Answer (score 1):

`select max(A) as A, max(B) as B, max(C) as C, max(D) as D from my_table`;